# Casting unix time to date in Presto

Tags: presto

I have timestamps stored in time since epoch (ms) and I would like to query and display results using a date formatted like 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`cast(from_unixtime(unixtime) as date)`

See https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html for more datetime functions.

Comment: cast((from_unixtime(unixtime)) as date) this worked for me.

Comment: the unixtime is in ms as per the question, hence we should be using `cast(from_unixtime(unixtime/1000) as date)`

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned   [`epoc(ms)`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)
division by 1000 would convert it to seconds.

**date(from_unixtime(min(ts)/1000))**

This helped me my epoch time is saved as BigInt and stored to be accurate to milliseconds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Use following to get the answer in YYYY-MM-DD format

```
format_datetime(from_unixtime(unixtime), 'Y-MM-dd')
```

Example:

```
format_datetime(from_unixtime(1664582792), 'Y-MM-dd')

Output --> 2022-10-01
```

Using cast as date as follows

```
cast(from_unixtime(1664582792) as date)
```

will give output as

```
2022-10-01 00:00:00.000
```