# Casting String type to Unix Date Amazon Athena

Tags: date, amazon-athena, presto

I'm looking to get a result in Amazon Athena were I can count the quantity of users created by day (or maybe by month)

But previous that I have to convert the unix timestamp to another date format. And this is where i fail.

My last goal is to convert this type of timestamp:

> 1531888605109

In something like:

> 2018-07-18

[According to Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

But when I try to apply the solution i saw in this quiestion: [Casting unix time to date in Presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420926/casting-unix-time-to-date-in-presto)

I got the error:

> [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:13: Unexpected parameters (varchar) for function from_unixtime. Expected: from_unixtime(double) , from_unixtime(double, bigint, bigint) , from_unixtime(double, varchar(x)) [SQL State=HY000, DB Errorcode=100071]

This is my query:

```
select   cast(from_unixtime(created)as date) as date_creation, 
         count(created) 
from     datalake.test
group by date_creation
```

Maybe I've to cast over the sctring because the data type of the field is not a date.

My table description: [Link to the table description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzM1S.jpg)

Comment: Maybe give a link to the version of Athena which you are using.

Comment: The error message is saying that `from_unixtime` expects a double, but the provided argument `created` is of type `varchar` (the SQL name for a Hive String type).  So you need something like list `from_unixtime(cast(created as DOUBLE))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> line 1:13: Unexpected parameters (varchar) for function from_unixtime. Expected: from_unixtime(double)

This means that your timestamps -- even though they appear numeric -- are `varchar`s.
You need to add a CAST to `cast(from_unixtime(created)as date)`, like:

```
CAST(from_unixtime(CAST(created AS bigint)) AS date)
```

Note: When dealing with time-related data, please have in mind that https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37 is not resolved yet in Presto.